# Passing ArrayList values dynamically to other ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have four arrays (say array1,array2....array4) of same length and I want to pass the values of these arrays dynamically to the `example array` so that I can add condition and get the values accordingly. How do I do that?

```
   public SectionListItem[] exampleArray = { // Comment to prevent re-format
           new SectionListItem("array1 data","array2 data","array3 data", "array4 data")

    };

    private StandardArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private SectionListAdapter sectionAdapter;
    private SectionListView listView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        arrayAdapter = new StandardArrayAdapter(this, R.id.example_text_view, exampleArray);
        sectionAdapter = new SectionListAdapter(getLayoutInflater(), arrayAdapter);

        listView = (SectionListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);



        setListAdapter(sectionAdapter);
        listView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple example:

```
public class array3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ar3[]={33,45,67,87,34,56};
        int ar4[]={5,8,9,22,3,4};
        List list1=new ArrayList();
        List list2=new ArrayList();
         for (int i = 0; i < ar3.length; i++) {
            list1.add(ar3[i]);
        }
   for (int i = 0; i < ar4.length; i++) {
            list2.add(ar4[i]);
        }
        list1.addAll(list2);
        System.out.println(list);           
    }
}
```